# Distributed transaction and Read Committed Snapshot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, distributed-transactions, snapshot-isolation

Distributed transactions are not supported for snapshot isolation level in SQL Server 2008 R2. But what about read committed snapshot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes RCSI is supported for use with distributed transactions as documented in Books Online:

[Choosing Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188277%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[image: BOL extract]